# Why the `unset` does not work as expected?

Tags: cmake

Here is the shell script which invokes the `cmake`

```
rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -DPULISH_VERSION=ON
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

option(WITH_FOO "whether FOO is enabled or not" on)
option(PULISH_VERSION "whether is the pulished verion or not" on)

if(PULISH_VERSION)
    if(WITH_FOO)
        message("FOO should not be enabled for the published version.")
        unset(WITH_FOO) # It seems `WITH_FOO` does not work, what a surprise!
    endif()
endif()

if(WITH_FOO)
    message("Attention! FOO is enabled!")
    add_compile_definitions(WITH_FOO_ENABLED)
endif()

add_executable(demo main.c)
```

Here is the content of the `main.c`:

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

Here is the output when the aforementioned shell script is called:

```
cmake .. -DPULISH_VERSION=ON                               
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
FOO should not be enabled for the published version.
Attention! FOO is enabled!
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/John/demo/build
```

As per the output above, it seems the `unset` does not work as expected. What a surprise!

Comment: AFIK: If you rerun cmake you might get the result expected because is cached the unset.

Comment: @Joel I delete the whole build folder, then rerun `cmake`, not work indeed. You can have a try.

Answer (score 2):

`WITH_FOO` is the option, a cache variable, not a scope (local) variable. `unset(WITH_FOO)` tries to unset the scope variable `WITH_FOO`, that does not exits. The scope variable does not exist and `if(WITH_FOO)` fallbacks to the value of the option `WITH_FOO`. You might want to set the variable `set(WITH_FOO OFF)` that will hide the option value.

There is a better choice - cmake dependent option:

```
cmake_dependent_option(WITH_FOO "whether FOO is enabled or not" ON "NOT PULISH_VERSION" OFF)
```

Makes `WITH_FOO` option `ON` if `PULISH_VERSION` is `OFF`. Otherwise, a local variable named `WITH_FOO` is set to `OFF`.

Comment: ***1***. What about the `DPULISH_VERSION` in the command ` cmake .. -DPULISH_VERSION=ON `? Does it influence the option(i.e. `DPULISH_VERSION`) in the `CMakeLists.txt`. As far as I know, the answer is yes. ***2***. If there is no `DPULISH_VERSION` option in the `CMakeLists.txt` while the command line does not change, then `DPULISH_VERSION` is a variable other than option now?

Comment: I seemed to fully answer your question. What is the comment for? If you have another specific question, try to create a new post.

Comment: Any wrong with the expression below? `option(WITH_FOO "with FOO or not" on);
cmake_dependent_option(WITH_FOO "whether FOO is enabled or not" ON "NOT PULISH_VERSION" OFF)`. For details, see my answer.

Comment: The first option is unnecessary. It's redefined by the second dependent option.

Comment: The fallback still confuses me. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74727604/13611002) is the question about it.

Comment: "`WITH_FOO` is the option, not a variable" - From the CMake terminology, `WITH_FOO` is a **cache variable**. It is not unset by `unset(WITH_FOO)` because the latter unsets only a **normal variable**. (But `unset(WITH_FOO CACHE)` will actually unsets the variable which is set by `option()` or in the command line). [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables) has extended description of how normal and cache variable are processed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, updated to using cmake terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @273k

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

include(CMakeDependentOption)

option(PULISH_VERSION "whether is the pulished verion or not" on)

cmake_dependent_option(WITH_FOO "whether FOO is enabled or not" ON "NOT PULISH_VERSION" OFF)

if(WITH_FOO)
    message("Attention! FOO is enabled!")
    add_compile_definitions(WITH_FOO_ENABLED)
endif()

add_executable(demo main.c)
```