# The fallback between variable and the `option`

Tags: cmake

As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74724928/13611002), which says that[emphasize mine]:

> `WITH_FOO` is the option, not a variable. `unset(WITH_FOO)` tries to unset the variable `WITH_FOO`, that does not exits. ***The variable does not exist and `if(WITH_FOO)` fallbacks to value of the option `WITH_FOO`***. You might want to set the variable `set(WITH_FOO OFF)`.

How to understand the fallback in the right way?

The command line `cmake .. -DMacro_name=value` always defines a variable? And the `option` does not define a `variable` if there is no variable with the same name has been defined?

Here is the shell script which invokes the `cmake`

```
rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -DPULISH_VERSION=ON
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

option(WITH_FOO "whether FOO is enabled or not" on)
option(PULISH_VERSION "whether is the pulished verion or not" on)

if(PULISH_VERSION)
    if(WITH_FOO)
        message("FOO should not be enabled for the published version.")
        unset(WITH_FOO) 
    endif()
endif()

if(WITH_FOO)
    message("Attention! FOO is enabled!")
    add_compile_definitions(WITH_FOO_ENABLED)
endif()

add_executable(demo main.c)
```

Comment: Have you read [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) for the `option` command? It clearly specifies that `option` does nothing if the variable is already set.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of [the `-D` command line option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D): it does result in a cache variable being set.